# Как убрать тень у выпадающего списка QComboBox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qss, qcombobox

Можно ли как-то убрать тень у списка? И как поменять цвет выделения вместо стандартного синего?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И что эта за пунктированная рамка такая? 
Как ее убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Style Sheets Examples http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

StyleSheet = '''
QComboBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 1px 18px 1px 3px;
    min-width: 6em;
}

QComboBox:editable {
    background: white;    /*white; red*/
}

QComboBox:!editable, QComboBox::drop-down:editable {
     background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                 stop: 0 #E1E1E1, stop: 0.4 #DDDDDD,
                                 stop: 0.5 #D8D8D8, stop: 1.0 #D3D3D3);
}

/* QComboBox получает состояние `on`, когда всплывающее окно открыто  */
QComboBox:!editable:on, QComboBox::drop-down:editable:on {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                stop: 0 #D3D3D3, stop: 0.4 #D8D8D8,
                                stop: 0.5 #DDDDDD, stop: 1.0 #E1E1E1);
}

QComboBox:on { /* сдвиньте текст, когда всплывающее окно откроется */
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 4px;
}

QComboBox::drop-down {
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 15px;

    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: darkgray;
    border-left-style: solid;          /* просто одна строка */
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;      /* тот же радиус, что и QComboBox */
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow {
    /*image: url(/usr/share/icons/crystalsvg/16x16/actions/1downarrow.png);*/
    image: url(16_16.jpg);
}

QComboBox::down-arrow:on { /* сдвиньте стрелку, когда всплывающее окно открыто */
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
}

/* Всплывающее окно QComboBox представляет собой QAbstractItemView и 
   оформляется с использованием селектора потомок: */
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    border: 2px solid darkgray;
    selection-background-color: lightgray;
}

QComboBox QListView {
    border: none;     
}
'''

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.resize(200, 200)
                
        lay   = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        combo.addItems(["option1", "option2", "option3"])
        lay.addWidget(combo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(200, 200)

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        combo.addItems(["option1", "option2", "option3"])
        lay.addWidget(combo)

     
StyleSheet = '''
QComboBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 1px 18px 1px 3px;
    min-width: 6em;
}
QComboBox:editable {
    background: white;    /*white; red*/
}
QComboBox:!editable, QComboBox::drop-down:editable {
     background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                 stop: 0 #E1E1E1, stop: 0.4 #DDDDDD,
                                 stop: 0.5 #D8D8D8, stop: 1.0 #D3D3D3);
}
/* QComboBox получает состояние `on`, когда всплывающее окно открыто  */
QComboBox:!editable:on, QComboBox::drop-down:editable:on {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                stop: 0 #D3D3D3, stop: 0.4 #D8D8D8,
                                stop: 0.5 #DDDDDD, stop: 1.0 #E1E1E1);
}
QComboBox:on { /* сдвиньте текст, когда всплывающее окно откроется */
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
QComboBox::drop-down {
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: darkgray;
    border-left-style: solid;          /* просто одна строка */
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;      /* тот же радиус, что и QComboBox */
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
QComboBox::down-arrow {
    width: 0;
    border: none;
}
QComboBox::down-arrow:on { 
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
}
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    border: 12px solid darkgray;
    selection-background-color: lightgray;
}
QComboBox QListView {
    border: none;
}
'''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')                                           # +++
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 10, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Два, маленьких вопроса. Как можно убрать или спрятать кнопку? И что за рамка пунктирная? Можно ее убрать?

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov я обновил свой ответ, попробуйте

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov я ответил на ваш вопрос?